# How to make a command block give the instant damage status effect to a player who steps in the pressure plate?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I can't do it also I will need the clear effect command too.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! On Minecraft commands questions, please see our [guide on what to do before asking a Minecraft commands question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797), especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far”, and edit in the requested information to your post.

Comment: If the posted answer solved your problem please consider accepting it by clicking the green tick

Answer (score 5):

You just need a command block under the pressure plate, set it as "impulse" and "needs redstone" with the following code:

```
execute as @p run effect @s instant_damage
```

You can change the [effect command](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Commands/effect) adding some parameters, this is `/effect` syntax:

```
effect <player: target> <effect: Effect> [seconds: int] [amplifier: int] [hideParticles: Boolean]
```

with these optional parameters:

- `seconds`, the effect duration
- `amplifier`, the effect power
- `hideParticles`, to hide its particles

---

To remove the effect (every effect) from a command block, the command is:

```
execute as @p run effect @s clear
```

or you can simply set a low duration for the above command.